# BLE Pairing from microcontroller

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

As part of my requirement, we need to have paring connection between microcontroller (Cortox M3) and Mobile or Pc. We are using Alpwise stack for our purpose. My problem is with the controller configurations, not with the mobile, because without paring i am able to work with it.
Where should i the API "BLESMP_InitiatePairing" api. Presently i am calling the api inside GAP_callback function, inside BLEGAP_EVENT_CONNECTED.
Is this a correct location to call at this API, because if i call over here, control goes to BLEEVENT_PAIRING_COMPLETE (returning SMERROR_UNKNOWREASON) then it goes into BLEEVENT_PAIRING_REQUEST then once again it goes into
BLEEVENT_PAIRING_COMPLETE (returning SMERROR_UNKNOWREASON). Whereas when i call "BLESMP_InitiatePairing" api, it returns me with success message

Comment: I have configured microcontroller as advertising mode and made the configuration

Answer (score 0):

(You listed the core-bluetooth tag, so I'm assuming you want to use iOS.)

I don't know the specific stack you are using. However, if you are developing an LE peripheral and want to connect with an iOS device as central, it is sufficient to reply to a read / write request with an InsufficientAuthentication error code. iOS will then initiate pairing from its side.

More details on this process can be found in the [Bluetooth Accessory Design Guidelines for Apple Products Section 3.9](https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf).